# Excel - From a matrix to a list

Tags: excel, list, matrix

I want to transform a matrix into a single column list.

Lets say I have this matrix:

```
qq|w|x|y|z
a |1| |2|
b | | |2|3
c |1|3|2|
```

and I want to make a list from it, like this:

```
a,1,2
b,2,3
c,1,3,2
```

edit: I'm using Excel 15.19 (for mac)

Comment: That depends on which Excel you are using.  If you are using the latest Office 365 it can be done with formulas.  If not it will need vba.

Comment: Edited: I'm using Excel 15.19 (for mac)

Comment: Then you will need vba, either a sub that does it all at once or a UDF that does it one by one.  In general, Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  You might get lucky, but since this has been answered many many times it may be faster to do a google search.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not expecting "code for me", but I can't use VBA because it doesn't work on office for mac.
What is the formula name for 365?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** through **E4**, in **F2** enter:

```
=A2 & "," & B2 & "," & C2 & "," & D2 & "," & E2
```

and copy down and in **G2** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(RIGHT(F2,1)=",",MID(F2,1,LEN(F2)-1),F2),",,",","),",,",",")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Never mind, there is a space in your quotes after the C2 it threw off my test.  Again you proved me wrong, I am amazed at times at your ability to come at questions from a different angle.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am amazed at **your** abilities with formulas!